# 30 amp dryer plug is hooked to a 40 amp double breaker, is this ok?

Tags: electrical, dryer

I just bought a home and needed to buy a new washer and dryer. The new dryers need a 30 amp plug, currently has 50 amp plug. I replaced the plug but noticed it was ran to a double pull 40 breaker, is this ok or do I need to replace breaker?

Comment: I have a similar setup. My 30 amp dryer outlet is wired with 10/3 wire to a 40 amp breaker. How could this have passed the initial inspection when the house was built, back in 1979?

Answer (score 3):

The breaker is primarily in place to protect the wiring. So first thing you should evaluate is the size (gauge) of wiring on this circuit. For a summary of normal copper wire usage:

1. Breaker 50A Wire Size 6 AWG
2. Breaker 40A Wire Size 8 AWG
3. Breaker 30A Wire Size 10 AWG
4. Breaker 20A Wire Size 12 AWG

It is also recommended practice on dedicated circuits like this *(circuit breaker via single branch wire run to single outlet)* that the outlet be also sized to the wire and breaker.

Now with that said there is no real problem with changing your outlet to a 30A style and changing the breaker to a 30A two pole breaker as long as the wire is 10AWG or larger size. There would be a strong recommendation that you make sure to use a 4-prong type 30A outlet, as opposed to the 3-prong type, so that you get the safety ground connection all the way to the appliance.

Comment: It's actually more than a recommended practice in this case, it's in the code - NEC 210.21(B)(1)

Comment: For DIY'ers, doesn't code" mean "recommended"  :)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the previous answer, the existing wiring is probably 8 gauge; as long as it's 10 gauge, it's adequate.  The receptacle should accept the wire either way - the terminals in the receptacles usually accept up to #4.

However it's actually more than a recommended practice in this case, it's in the code - NEC 210.21(B)(1) -

[image: NEC Table 210.21(B)(3)]

the breaker can't be 40 amp, it has to be swapped for a 30 amp.

Most dryers can operate with either a three wire cord with no ground, or with a four wire cord with a ground wire.  If the existing receptacle did have a ground wire, you have to replace it with a four wire grounded type - simple.

Likewise if there's a ground available in the box, you'll replace it with a grounded type, even if the existing 50A isn't the grounded type.

If your existing receptacle is three wire / ungrounded, and there is no ground available in the existing box, the code does have provisions [see 250.130(C)] when replacing an ungrounded receptacle:  you can use a new ungrounded receptacle, or run a ground wire to part of the existing grounding system and use a grounded receptacle.  However since in this case you're changing the type of receptacle, not replacing with the same type, that may be a stretch.  The safest bet would be to run a new 10/3 to the panel and connect it to the new 30A two pole breaker.